# HBase client program not able to identify/read existing table

Tags: java, hbase

I am trying to connect to HBase locally from my client Java Program when I get this error:

`Encountered problems when prefetch META table: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableNotFoundException: Cannot find row in .META. for table: "XYZ", row="XYZ",,99999999999999`

HBase Version: `hbase-0.94.0`

What I've already tried:

1. Double checking the configurations
2. Making sure that the table exists (And yes it is visible from the shell)
3. Deleting the `.META.` folder in hbase datasource directory
4. Deleting the local datasource folder
5. Tried running `hbck -repair` which apparently shows 0 inconsistencies

I've tried all of the above, but still no success.

I tried to do some googling of this error message, and found out that this was a HBase bug which was supposedly solved in HBase-0.94.0 release. But i don't know why I'm still facing this problem.

Can someone please help me out ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was that there was an illegal character in my table name which could not be parsed and hence the exception was thrown. Still, I'm surprised at why it had to throw such an exception instead of just notifying that the table wasn't available.